# Changing from port 3306 to 3308 not working

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I load xampp, it tells me that I should change port numbers, which is probably because I am using mysql command line.

So I went to \xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini and changed to listen to port 3308...but when I reload xampp, It still shows me the same error and that I am listening to port 3306 still.

Below the screen:

[image]

How can I change from port 3306 to 3308

Comment: Pleas add your config file here as well so we can see what changes you made

Comment: click **config** on the xampp control panel, there should be a field to configure the port xampp control panel should check for mysql. do double check your `my.ini` though, it configures the actual port being used by mysql.. i know its a bit redundant. as long as you can start or stop mysql, its good.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change port 3306 to 3308 in xampp\php\php.ini

Also try this 
1. Open Task Manager > Services Tab
2. Find "mysqlweb" service > right-click it to stop service
3. Then launch XAMPP again

Comment: I would like to know whether above solution worked for you? Else we could figure out something else

Santosh Ulbetti